# Rewrite rules in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to make rewrite rules within .htaccess file of my server.

I can make it work on very simple urls like

```
example.com/contact.php
```

to

```
example.com/contact/
```

But when I have a little more complex url I can't make it work.

My url is this:

```
example.com/hotels/hotelPage.php?go&hotelname=NAME&hotelId=NUMBER
```

I want this to be accessible like this

```
example.com/hotels/NAME-NUMBER/
```

Is that possible ? I have tried versions like:

```
RewriteRule    ^hotels/(\w+)/?$    hotels/hotelPage.php?go&hotelname=$1    [NC,L]
```

And this one:

```
RewriteRule    ^hotels/^[A-Za-z-]+/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    hotels/hotelPage.php?go&hotelname=$1    [NC,L]
```

None seems to work for me.

Comment: .htcaccess? Do you mean .htaccess? Or is this some HTC-phone-specific website access file?

Comment: Your two examples are completely different, one - the first - rewrites the URL , the other - the second - takes GET variables and uses them as URL placeholders.

Comment: _“Is that possible ?”_ – of course it is. But since URL rewriting is a topic that is documented quite detailed as well broadly discussed already, I’d say you should to do some proper research on this, instead of just asking “is it possible”.

Comment: can you post the rules that you have and maybe what you've tried?

Comment: @Martin, sorry it is .htaccess of course.

Comment: you may want to consider a structure more like /hotels/number/name-which-may-have-dashes. your current structure would require some odd rules if the number is part of the slug and the name has more than one word joined by a dash, which is typical.

Comment: @CBroe, sorry for the short questions, have tried to read up on it , and tried various versions on this URL. I have listed the variations I've tried.

Comment: @Kai Qing /hotels/number/name-which-may-have-dashes - would also be fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're close, try:

```
RewriteRule ^hotels/^([A-Za-z-]+)-([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$    hotels/hotelPage.php?go&hotelname=$1&hotelId=$2 [NC,L]
```

This regex assumes that the first grouping is the hotel name: `([A-Za-z-]+)`

and the second is the hotel id: `([A-Za-z0-9]+)`

so the hotel name can *only* be letters and dashes, while the id can be letters and numbers. The ID can't have any dashes because the first regex would greedily gobble them all up except for the last one.

Comment: I get a 404 still with this - do I need to set base url maybe ?

Comment: I have server on Godaddy